# new token liquidity and price

Tags: erc-20

if I have a new token that has a total supply of 420 trillion and I want to have 20% liquidity for it, how much of the token and ether would I need to put in to get this

Answer (score 0):

Funny you bring this up now because the Team I am in making a project with is on a similar topic. I'll try to explain some of this in here, but having a voice conversation over discord makes it a lot easier, so if you want to talk deeper, find me in this discord: https://discord.gg/P4Ngyr9pcM

So It depends on what you mean by "have 20% liquidity for it". Often in tokenomics papers you'll see percentages of funds being allocated for different things. Everything from community rewards, to marketing, to team compensation. If the 20% you referred to was a tokenomics distribution of 20%, then that means 20% of the total market cap is being reserved to be potentially used in the pairs in different decentralized exchanges, but it doesn't necessarily require all of them to be used.

So 20% of 420 trillion is 84 trillion. Of that 84 trillion, likely you would only use a portion of it in the liquidity pair. usually only a small portion of those funds are injected into the liquidity pool, so lets assume 10 trillion are used in the first liquidity pair, while 74 trillion are held for future DEXs.

Now we've chosen 10 trillion as the first part of the pair, the next step is choosing how much funds to put in the second part of that pair, and whether it's USDT or Eth or some other token variation.

This is part where the group I'm in are discussing now. How much IRL funds to put along side that pair. Minimum we were discussing might be along the lines of 1 to 2k, so that small price action doesn't cause a too big of a jump in price, while also not creating massive holder differences. Though this is speculative on our end. Come join me on discord if you'd like and we can research this detail together.

Answer (score 0):

20% of 420 trillion = (20/100) * 420 trillion = 84 trillion tokens.

Therefore, you would need to allocate 84 trillion tokens and an equivalent value of Ether to provide 20% liquidity for the token.